# Best Practices for Creating a Subscriber or Membership System

Tags: database, algorithm, security

I would like to inquire about how to create a subscriber or membership system. Is it as straightforward as adding a "type_member" column to the database?

If not, what other factors should be taken into consideration when developing a subscriber or membership system?

Comment: No one will be able to tell, as it depends on whether this satisfies all the requirements your application faces or not. This question needs much more focus.